# Why erb blocks concatenate the block content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have the following code:

```rb
require 'erb'

def body &block
  content = block.call
  content = block.call
  content = block.call
  content
end

x = 2
template = ERB.new <<-EOF
  <% body do %>
     2
  <% end %>
EOF

template.run(binding)
```

When I execute it outputs `2 2 2`. Why in each call to `block.call` inside the `body` method it is concatenating the content of the block?

Why if I use the following template it doesn't happens:

```rb
template = ERB.new <<-EOF
  <%= body do
     2
  end %>
EOF
```

I can't get my mind around what's happening here. I had this problem with rails but isolated the code to plain Ruby to try to understand what the problem was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because how ERB works. See erb-generated ruby source for your templates (`template.src`, below is prettified), for the former template:

```rb
_erbout = +''
_erbout.<< "  ".freeze
body do
  _erbout.<< "\n     2\n  ".freeze      # <<-- this is the line that produces extra output
end
_erbout.<< "\n".freeze
_erbout
```

and for the latter:

```rb
_erbout = +''
_erbout.<< "  ".freeze
_erbout.<<(( body do
     2                                  # <<- and this time it is just plain ruby code
  end
).to_s)
_erbout.<< "\n".freeze
_erbout
```

note how blocks output to the same buffer when being run.

Actually this is normal and is widely used, for example for the below block that's passed to `each` method you expect output from each run to be concatenated:

```
<% @items.each do |item| %>
  Item <%= item %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks! this was exactly what I was expecting to find as an answer :)!. Didn't new ERB has a src method.